# Type for basic HTML tags?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have an exported type called `Tags` that defines available tags for some components:

```
export type Tags =
  | 'div'
  | 'article'
  | 'section'
  | 'aside'
  | 'nav'
  | 'figure'
  | 'main'
  | 'header'
  | 'footer';
```

Obviously, this is something that I've written myself and have to update anytime I want to add a tag; does something like this exist already? Similar to React's `HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget`?

Comment: No, TypeScript does not have any built-in `type` defined as a subset of any of the HTML element names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through React's index.d.ts, I see an `interface ReactHTML` that looks to contain many (and only) built-in HTML tags as keys. The values of the object type are `DetailedHTMLFactory`s, but you can ignore those and just look at the keys.

```
import { ReactHTML } from 'react';

type BuiltInHTMLTag = keyof ReactHTML;
const div: BuiltInHTMLTag = 'div'; // OK
const nope: BuiltInHTMLTag = 'doesntexist'; // Error
```